# What is a simple regular expression to rename multiple files?

Tags: regex

Suppose that, on a UNIX system, I have a directory that contains the files `abc.css`, `abc.js`, and `abc.html`. In the console, is there a command that I can run that will rename the files to `xyz.css`, `xyz.js`, and `xyz.html`, respectively?

The solution that I'm envisioning is some combination of mv and a regular expression, but I'm not sure exactly how to combine the two.

Answer (score 1):

What OS?

In Windows you don’t need regular expressions. A simple wildcard should suffice:

```
>ren abc.* xyz.*
```

Comment: For some reason, that didn't work for me. It gave me the typical "usage: mv ..." error response that it gives when the command syntax is incorrect.

Comment: What OS?​​​​​​​

Comment: What? No, that will get expanded to `mv abc.css abc.js abc.html xyz.css xyz.js xyz.html`. Have you tested this?

Comment: @ChristianMann, yes I did and it worked as expected in Windows.

Comment: `mv` isn't a command in cmd.exe. Are you in PowerShell, Cygwin, or an SSH connection to a Linux box?

Comment: @Synetech I'm working in Mac OSX. I just edited the question to reflect that for future interweb-travelers.

Comment: @ChristianMann, I used `ren` which is the same as `move` (which should be the same as `mv` in other OSes). I don’t know what will work on Mac though.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux the `rename` command will work:

> rename abc xyz "abc.*"